# ajax script is not working on live server

Tags: php, ajax, controller

when i m running my project on local host then the ajax is working properly. but when i m uploading it on server then its not working... please tell me the sollution

This is my Controller

```
    public function select_subcategory()
{
$str='<option value="">Select Option</option>';  
            $id=$this->input->post('id');
            $res=$this->db->query("Select * from tn_topic_subcategory where category='".$id."'")->result();
            foreach($res as $key)
            {
                $str.='<option value="'.$key->subcategory_id.'">'.$key->sub_ctg_name.'</option>';
            }

            echo $str;
}
```

And this is my Ajax

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
  function change_cat(id)

   {

 $.ajax({type:'post',
        url:'<?PHP echo base_url()?>admin/select_subcategory',
        data:{id:id},
        success:function(res){
                            // alert(res);
                              $('#topic-subcategory').html(res);
                             }
      });
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please provide error message displayed in console

Comment: its not showing any error message

Comment: Can you confirm that your ajax request going to your function select_subcategory() without error.

Comment: ya its working on local server

Comment: Please confirm this for live serve . I think you have problem with your ajax request url on live server

Comment: thnx dude its working now ... i changed the base url with admin_link_url

Answer (score 0):

If you are supposed to get your response in json format then try below code.
it will help you to send your variable in json format.

```
    {

     $.ajax({type:'post',
            url:'<?PHP echo base_url();?>admin/select_subcategory',
            data:{id:id},
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(res){
                                // alert(res);
                                  $('#topic-subcategory').html(res);
                                 }
          });
       }
```

Also try to send your response in json encoded.
I hope it will work for you.

Thanks